# Creating a PDF based on a template using Python

Tags: python, django, templates, pdf

I need to create a PDF that contains some text and text boxes, that should appear over a letterhead template for my company. It will cover multiple pages - and each page should have hte letterhead as the background (cant be an image sicne the links and so on in the letter head need to be clickable and the text copyable).

Any idea how I can do this using python?? It would ideally come out of a django web app..

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why don't you just give it a try?  The tools exist, it's not clear what you need from us.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to create PDFs in python. The [reportlab](http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/) library is probably the easiest. And it is [supported by django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-pdf/).

Answer (score 0):

I use reportlab, it works well. But it takes some time learning how to draw pdf and design your code. You need to draw everything using code.

If your requirement is simple, you can use some html to pdf freamwork instead of reportlab(rml is not free), such as pisa. It's simple.

Wish it helps you.